# Null check operator used on a null value FutureBuilder<Object?>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<Object?>#11868

Tags: ios, flutter, ipad

I am new to flutter I get this issue this issue only show on iPad on iPhone app working just fine

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Object?>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<Object?>#11868):
Null check operator used on a null value

## The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder<Object?> FutureBuilder:file:///Volumes/Data%201/Elmasria_App_2/user_App/lib/Screens/course_details_screen.dart:667:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _CourseDetailScreenState.unPurchasedCourseDetails (package:eclass/Screens/course_details_screen.dart:451:107)
#1      _CourseDetailScreenState.detailsSection (package:eclass/Screens/course_details_screen.dart:1062:15)
#2      _CourseDetailScreenState.scaffoldBody.<anonymous closure> (package:eclass/Screens/course_details_screen.dart:678:17)
#3      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:612:55)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5198:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5086:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#8      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#11     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#12     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5162:5)
#13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#16     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5162:5)
#17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#18     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#19     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#20     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#23     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#24     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#26     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6093:32)
#27     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6595:17)
#28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#31     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#34     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#36     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#39     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#41     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#44     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#45     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#47     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#48     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#49     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#50     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#52     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#54     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#55     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#56     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#61     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#62     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#63     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#64     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#65     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#66     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#67     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#68     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#69     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#70     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#71     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#72     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#73     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#74     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#75     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#76     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#77     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#78     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#79     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#80     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#82     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#83     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#84     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#85     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#86     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#87     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#88     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#89     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#90     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#91     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#92     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#93     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#94     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#95     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#96     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#97     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#98     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#99     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#100    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#101    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#102    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#103    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#104    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#105    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5162:5)
#106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#107    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#108    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#109    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#110    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#111    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#112    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#113    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#114    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#115    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#116    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6093:32)
#117    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6595:17)
#118    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#119    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#120    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#121    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#122    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#123    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#124    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#125    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#126    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#127    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#128    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#129    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#130    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#131    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#132    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#133    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#134    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#135    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#136    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#138    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#139    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#140    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#141    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#142    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#143    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#144    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#145    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#146    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#147    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5162:5)
#148    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#149    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#150    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#151    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#152    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#153    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#154    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#155    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#156    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#157    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#158    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#159    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#160    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#161    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#162    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#163    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#164    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#165    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#166    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#167    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#168    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#169    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#170    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#171    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#172    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#173    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#174    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#175    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#176    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#177    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#178    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#179    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#180    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#181    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#182    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#183    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5162:5)
#184    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#185    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#186    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#187    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5162:5)
#188    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#189    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#190    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#191    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#192    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#193    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#194    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#195    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#196    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#197    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#198    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#199    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#200    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#201    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#202    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#203    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#204    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#205    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#206    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#207    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#208    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#209    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#210    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#211    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#212    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#213    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#214    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#215    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#216    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#217    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:939:7)
#221    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)

`your text`
issue only show on iPad on iPhone app working just fine

my _app.dart

```
    import 'package:eclass/Screens/blog_list_screen.dart';
    import 'package:eclass/Screens/terms_policy.dart';
    import 'package:eclass/localization/language_screen.dart';
    import 'package:eclass/player/offline/downloads_screen.dart';
    import 'package:eclass/provider/InstituteDetailsProvider.dart';
    import 'package:eclass/provider/blog_provider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/localization/language_provider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/InstituteProvider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/compareCourseProvider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/currenciesProvider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/manual_payment_provider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/terms_policy_provider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/walletDetailsProvider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/provider/watchlist_provider.dart';
import 'package:eclass/screens/compare_course_screen.dart';
import 'package:eclass/screens/currency_screen.dart';
import 'package:eclass/screens/wallet_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_translate/flutter_translate.dart';
import 'Screens/loading_screen.dart';
import 'gateways/donate.dart';
import 'provider/cart_provider.dart';
import 'provider/content_provider.dart';
import 'provider/course_details_provider.dart';
import 'provider/recent_course_provider.dart';
import 'Screens/faq_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/instructor_faq_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/about_us_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/became_instructor_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/bundle_detail_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/category_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/child_category_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/contact_us_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/course_details_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/course_instructor_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/courses_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/edit_profile.dart';
import 'Screens/filter_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/forgot_password.dart';
import 'Screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/sign_in_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/notification_detail_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/notifications_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/purchase_history_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/sign_up_screen.dart';
import 'Screens/sub_category_screen.dart';
import 'provider/bundle_course.dart';
import 'provider/cart_pro_api.dart';
import 'provider/filter_pro.dart';
import 'provider/home_data_provider.dart';
import 'provider/payment_api_provider.dart';
import 'provider/visible_provider.dart';
import 'provider/wish_list_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'provider/courses_provider.dart';
import 'provider/user_details_provider.dart';
import 'common/theme.dart' as T;
import 'provider/user_profile.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  String? token;
  MyApp(this.token);
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => UserDetailsProvider()), // Fetch User Details
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => T.Theme()), // Theme Data
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProfile()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WishListProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CoursesProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CartProducts()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FilterDetailsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BundleCourseProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => HomeDataProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Visible()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => RecentCourseProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PaymentAPIProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ContentProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CourseDetailsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BlogProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CartProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LanguageProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TermsPolicyProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WatchlistProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ManualPaymentProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => InstituteProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => InstituteDetailsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CompareCourseProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WalletDetailsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CurrenciesProvider()),
      ],
      child: LocalizationProvider(
        state: LocalizationProvider.of(context).state,
        child: MaterialApp(
          navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            localizationDelegate
          ],
          supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
          locale: localizationDelegate.currentLocale,
          home: token == null ? SignInScreen() : LoadingScreen(token),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Mada'),
          routes: {
            '/SignIn': (context) => SignInScreen(),
            '/courseDetails': (context) => CourseDetailScreen(),
            '/InstructorScreen': (context) => CourseInstructorScreen(),
            '/homeScreen': (context) => HomeScreen(),
            '/CoursesScreen': (context) => CoursesScreen(),
            '/signUp': (context) => SignUpScreen(),
            '/category': (context) => CategoryScreen(),
            '/subCategory': (context) => SubCategoryScreen(),
            '/childCategory': (context) => ChildCategoryScreen(),
            '/forgotPassword': (context) => ForgotPassword(),
            '/editProfile': (context) => EditProfile(),
            "/bundleCourseDetail": (context) => BundleDetailScreen(),
            "/filterScreen": (context) => FilterScreen(),
            '/notifications': (context) => NotificationScreen(),
            '/becameInstructor': (context) => BecomeInstructor(),
            '/aboutUs': (context) => AboutUsScreen(),
            '/purchaseHistory': (context) => PurchaseHistoryScreen(),
            '/contactUs': (context) => ContactUsScreen(),
            '/notificationDetail': (context) => NotificationDetail(),
            '/userFaq': (context) => FaqScreen(),
            '/instructorFaq': (context) => InstructorFaqScreen(),
            '/blogList': (context) => BlogListScreen(),
            '/languageScreen': (context) => LanguageScreen(),
            '/termsPolicy': (context) => TermsPolicy(),
            '/donate': (context) => Donate(),
            '/downloads': (context) => DownloadsScreen(),
            '/currency': (context) => CurrencyScreen(),
            '/compare': (context) => CompareCourseScreen(),
            '/wallet': (context) => WalletScreen(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include sample code code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: I update with my_app.dart